# Don't reload DropDownList when OnClick ASP Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

I'm trying save the value of a DropDownList when I press a Button, but when I press this, it appears that refresh page and ever get the index 0 of the DropDownList.
Here's the code from method `btnAccept_Click` from .cs:

```
if (comboOpciones.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    if (serv.modifyMovie(comboModifica.selectedIndex + 1, textboxTitulo.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textboxAño.Text), textBoxGenero.Text, textboxNacionalidad.Text, 0) == 1)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptkey", "<script>alert(' Succesful Modify ');</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptkey", "<script>alert(' Unsuccesful modify');</script>");
    }
}
```

The value 'comboModifica.selectedIndex' returns all the time the index 0

Here the code of my web form ASP:

```
<table class="centrada">
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>¿Qué desea hacer?</p>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="comboOpciones" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="comboOpciones_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem>Añadir</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Modificar</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div runat="server" id="divModificar">
        <p>Introduce ID de película a modificar:</p>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="comboModifica" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Nuevo título:"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="textboxTitulo" runat="server" MaxLength="30"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>

    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Año:"></asp:Label>

    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="textboxAño" runat="server" MaxLength="4"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Género:"></asp:Label>

    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxGenero" runat="server" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Nacionalidad:"></asp:Label>

    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="textboxNacionalidad" runat="server" MaxLength="25"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Director:"></asp:Label>

    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="comboDirectores" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <asp:Button ID="btnAccept" runat="server" Text="Enviar" AutoPostBack="false" OnClick="btnAccept_Click"/>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How Can I get the DropDownList's value?

Comment: how and when are you populating your "comboOpciones"?

Comment: I'm populating this dropdownlist in the ASP code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that, the combobox get initialized in each postback. So you need to identify whether it is a postback or not. The init the combobox only when it is not a postback. Let `BindMyCbo()` is the method that's binds all values to the Required comboBox, Here it is `comboModifica`. Then you need to call the method only when The page load is not a [PostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx). so the method call(within your page_load event) will be like the following:

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindMyCbo();
        //Rest of code
    }
```

So the combobox get initialized in page load and remains same after postback

Comment: I need to make this call when the Page is load?

Comment: yes absolutely. include the three lines of code in `page_load`

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. I can't vote you, but your answer works to me.

Comment: @cnbandicoot: That's not a problem. Have a nice time